# i am trying to get LeakCanary to log to logCat

Tags: leakcanary

I have leakCanary installed and working but I never see logcat messages for it.  I would also like to see the dump file in Android Studio as well. It is not clear to me how to do this. (I have not worked much with the memory analyzer *yet*)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any filters in `Logcat` window. Type `Leak` in input and you'll be able to see something like:

```
04-26 11:26:51.990 1548-1875/your.package.debug D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: FINDING_LEAKING_REFS
04-26 11:26:51.990 1548-1875/your.package.debug D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: FINDING_SHORTEST_PATHS
04-26 11:27:00.590 1548-1581/your.package.debug D/LeakCanary: Checking retained references because had pending heap dump
04-26 11:27:00.590 1548-1581/your.pacakge.debug D/LeakCanary: Leak Analysis in progress, will retry in 20000 ms
```